# Knockout computed observables extremely slows down browser on larger datasets

Tags: javascript, jquery, mvvm, knockout.js

I'm working with nested ViewModel-Objects and KnockoutJS and ran into annoying troubles using it. lets say you have a nested Model like this:

> -Totals (Some totalization of all Clients, contains Array of ClientsContainer, ~10 Computed observables)
>
> -ClientContainer (Some totalization of all Clients MoneyAccounts, Contains Array of MoneyAccounts, ~10 Computed observables)
>
> --MoneyAccounts (Some totalization of all AccountPositions, Contains Array of AccountPositions, ~25 Computed observables)
>
> ----AccountPositions (~25 Computed observables, ~25 Computed observables)

I mapped the viewModel from a JS structure (35 ClientsContainer, each Client Container contains about 10 MoneyAccount, each MoneyAccount contains about 2 Positions)

First, I figured out that the ComputedObservables on the AccountPositions were not refreshed after being initialized. So, I had to force that refresh using a dummyObservable in each ComputedFunction and then calling knockouts notifySubscribers()-Function.

It seems like this method is extremely expensive regarding performance, even if i have only about 700 AccountPositions over the whole ViewModel (which isn't that much..). I had to delay each refresh-Call by 500 Millisecons to prevent the browser from hanging up completely. Even now, my browser is very overwhelmed. It takes about 15Minutes to render my data table, which definitly should load faster..

What am I missing here? Are there "techniques" to load/initialize nested ViewModel structures faster? Or is Knockout simply unable to manage such data-sets with great performance?

Thanks in advance

Comment: We really need a repro to be able to help. In addition, let us know what specific browsers and ko-versions demonstrate the issue. Knockout should really be able to handle the numbers you mention, depending on the actual code of course.